# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infomentum.Detect.class

Tags: java, file, applet

I have jsp in which file upload feature is implemented using 'AppletFile' applet and it is working fine with java-6 version.
Here is the code to integrate 'AppletFile' applet into jsp :

```
<applet codebase="/uploadApplet" code="com.infomentum.Detect.class" id="Detect" name="Detect" width="1" height="1" viewastext mayscript></applet>
```

Issue occurred on machine having java-7 and below exception occcurred on java console :

```
    c:   clear console window
    f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
    g:   garbage collect
    h:   display this help message
    l:   dump classloader list
    m:   print memory usage
    o:   trigger logging
    q:   hide console
    r:   reload policy configuration
    s:   dump system and deployment properties
    t:   dump thread list
    v:   dump thread stack
    x:   clear classloader cache
    0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@46f3978d
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@2cf590bb
security: Expected Main URL: https://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com/uploadApplet/com/infomentum/Detect.class
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com/uploadApplet/com/infomentum/Detect.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com/uploadApplet/com/infomentum/Detect.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunec.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com/uploadApplet/com/infomentum/Detect/class.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com/uploadApplet/com/infomentum/Detect/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://iv3-manage.niit-mts.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infomentum.Detect.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class com.infomentum.Detect.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infomentum.Detect.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@2cf590bb
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

kindly suggest it is code issue  or some configuration issue with java-7

Comment: Try without the .class after the classname.

Comment: Is `com.infomentum.Detect.class` located as subdirectories `uploadApplet`

Answer (score 1):

When you reference a class in Java, just write its name. You do not have to add `.class` extension which is just a technical file system extension. So, you have to remove `.class` on `code="com.infomentum.Detect.class`:

```
<applet codebase="/uploadApplet" code="com.infomentum.Detect" id="Detect" name="Detect" width="1" height="1" viewastext mayscript></applet>
```

For example, in a Java class, you will have imports of other classes. You will see:
import `java.lang.Exception` and not `java.lang.Exception.class`.

A Java class is identified by a `package` name (similar to a Namespace) and a class name. `.class` is superfluous.